# Button connecting with a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am using Netbeans to create a Java desktop application. I have created two different `JPanel`s. In one I have inserted a button, and in the other just some settings. How can I connect the `JButton`, in the other `JPanel`, to change the settings of the other one? What code should I use? (Keep in mind that I am a beginner.)

Comment: If you want something to happen when the user clicks on the `JButton`, you should [add an `ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener-java.awt.event.ActionListener-) to it. Refer to [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) which is part of Oracle's java tutorials.

Comment: 1) *"I am using Netbeans.."* Sure, but don't add it as a tag unless the IDE is part of the problem (e.g. you've tried it in a different IDE and seen it work). 2) Don't extend components or containers (like `JPanel`) unless changing the existing functionality. One of the few valid cases I've seen for that, is when custom painting the panel content. 3) *"(Keep in mind that I am a beginner.)"* Keep in mind that making GUIs in Java is an advanced topic. Probably better to stick to non-GUI projects until you become more experienced. 4) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MRE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple programm. It dosen't matter if the button and the label are in the same JPanel or not.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));

JLabel label = new JLabel("Test string");

JButton button = new JButton("Push me");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        label.setText("change text");
    }
});
panel.add(label);
panel.add(button);

frame.add(panel);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: _It dosen't matter if the button and the label are in the same JPanel or not_ it may make a difference if each `JPanel` is defined in a different class. You may want to add such example. Consider posting [mre]. Also since you are setting preferred size there is no neet to set bounds. Just use `frame.pack();` before making the `JFrame` visible

Comment: _it may make a difference if each JPanel is defined in a different class_ that's true. that make a different. But nobody write that the second JPanel is an a different class. The question was: _How can I connect the JButton, in the other JPanel_ and for that it dosen't matter if the button and the label are in the same JPanel or not.